# How do I log Scrapy settings?

Tags: python, configuration, scrapy

Scrapy gets its settings from a number of sources -- environment parameters, a configuration file, programmatic settings -- so I want to log the effective settings to see what it's got.

How do I do that?

I would simply iterate over keys and values in Scrapy's  Settings object, but it does not expose the full interface of a dict as one might expect.

Comment: See Ronaldo's answer. The key point is to iterate over keys  of settings.attributes yet take values from settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the available attributes:

```
for name in crawler.settings.attributes:
    value = crawler.settings.get(name)
    print name, '=', repr(value)
```

Output:

```
CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT = 0
USER_AGENT = u'Scrapy/1.0.3 (+http://scrapy.org)'
HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
MEMUSAGE_REPORT = False
...
```

Comment: Ronaldo, I edited this to remove the "In [2]" from the beginning and to split code from sample output.